# How to interpret coefficients, cross-section versus panel with fixed effects

Tags: regression, time-series, interpretation, panel-data, regression-coefficients

I study the impact of a set of variables on the number of farm workers on long-term contracts. I have a panel with 8,000 geographic units and 6 years. I am particularly interested in one variable, pastoral, which measures the share of land, used for pastoral agriculture. The coefficient for this variable is positive in cross-sections for any year but becomes negative in a fixed-effects panel model. I am struggling to interpret this finding (the change of sign). Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the design correctly, but the first thing that comes to mind is that this is a case of [Simpson's paradox](https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/simpsons-paradox/): the relationship between pastoral and nr of workers is positive within each year but negative on average across years. If you look at the first image in the link and imagine pastoral is x and nr of workers is y and the different groups of points represent different years - could that be the case?

If so, you could try fitting a multilevel model with a random slope of pastoral using year as the random effect grouping variable.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good point! Is this the right model in R:                                     
model <- lmer(trans ~ pastoral + other variables + (pastoral | year), data = mydata)}?    Also, does it make sense to include fixed effects for geographic units?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that except I assume your dependent variable is a count (of workers) and can't be negative? If so, you should maybe use glmer with family=poisson instead of lmer. As for the geographic unit, how many levels would it have as fixed predictor? 8000? That will probably not work technically.

Comment: Originally my dependent variable was a share of workers on long-term contacts. As it is bounded between 0 and 1, I logit-transformed it. I agree that 8000 is too many units, but they can be grouped into 41 much larger counties. Which approach would you recommend?

Comment: OK in that case I'd put in either fixed effect of county or random intercept of county, like this (1|county). To me 41 levels feels a lot for a fixed predictor too so that's why I'd first consider random intercept but you have so many observations that each will probably work well and each controls for the effect of county on your other predictors' effects.

Comment: Great, thanks! Am I right to think that (1 | county) adds a random intercept, and (1 + county | year) adds a random slope? Both for each county. These are the models I have run, and the results are quite similar. How would you choose the 'best' one?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that! I think you can choose the model that makes most theoretical or practical sense. If you believe it's important to model the slope of county, use the random slope model, if not, use the random intercept model (the only reason I'd prefer the RI model is that 41 categorical random slopes makes a pretty complex model, but as it converges for you, that's not an issue).